# How to Add a Select All trigger in mat-select using Angular8/Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created this code:

```
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Handler Type</mat-label>
        <mat-select multiple [(value)]="handlerType">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let handlerType of handlerTypeSelect" [value]="handlerType">
            {{ handlerType.name }}
          </mat-option>
          <div class="etc-select-action-button">
            <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="selectAll()">
              <mat-icon>check_box_outline</mat-icon> <span>Select All</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="handlerType=undefined; $event.stopPropagation()">
              <mat-icon>check_box_outline_blank</mat-icon> <span>Clear All</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

[image]

I would like to have two buttons which selects all and clears all selected options. The clear all button works fine but the select all don't. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your selectAll method code?

Comment: selectAll(): void {
    this.handlerType = this.selectAll;
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign all value to handletType property when clicking selectAll method.

**Try this:**

```
selectAll(){
      this.handlerType = this.handlerTypeSelect;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 selectAll(select: NgModel, values, array) {
    select.update.emit(values); 
  }

  deselectAll(select: NgModel) {
    select.update.emit([]); 
  }
```

try this

or else

try this

```js
<mat-checkbox class="mat-option"
                    (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                    (change)="selectAll(/* Check to see if you want to check/uncheck all, do that here */)"
                    [indeterminate]="itemsSelected.length && itemsNotSelected.length"
                    [checked]="!itemsNotSelected.length">
        Select All
      </mat-checkbox>
```